# MFMailComposeViewController delegate not working on swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm trying to dismiss the MFMailComposeViewController but the delegate is not triggered. It seems that it's a common issue and the answers are the same, but they do not work for me :(. I have a button that calls the function to send the mail. I first create a csv file, then the MFMailComposeViewController and attach the csv file to the mail. The mail is sent sometimes (the mail view controller does not dismiss after that) and the cancel button shows me the option to delete or save the draft but after that nothing happens.

Here's the code of the button:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class UserInfoViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

@IBAction func uploadPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        let contentsOfFile = "Name,ID,Age,Sex,Time,\n\(name),\(id),\(age),\(sex),\(time)"

        let data = contentsOfFile.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)

        if let content = data {
            print("NSData: \(content)")
        }

        func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {

            let emailController = MFMailComposeViewController()

            //emailController.mailComposeDelegate = self as? MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
            emailController.mailComposeDelegate = self
            emailController.setToRecipients([""])
            emailController.setSubject("CSV File")
            emailController.setMessageBody("", isHTML: false)

            emailController.addAttachmentData(data!, mimeType: "text/csv", fileName: "registro.csv")

            return emailController

        }

        let emailViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()

        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {

            self.present(emailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

        func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {

            print("Delegate worked!")
            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is being caused by putting the delegate method inside another method. You can't do that. Delegate functions need to be at the top level of the class. Simply move your `mailComposeController(_:didFinishWith:error:)` function out of the `uploadPressed` function.